# Toast message if there is not data from server

Tags: java, android

i want to show in my search if it wont recieve similar result to my word i enterd it should Toast me "No Result.but problem is that it gets data after 0.5 seconds.so when i click button first it Toasts No results then gets data and show them in recyclerview.I want if there is not similar word it toast me No result at the end;

```
 String text = txtsearch.getText().toString();
             new AsyncTaskSearch("http://192.168.1.100/afgApp/search.php", text).execute();
                  final Timer timer = new Timer();
                    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                  if (!Activity_Search.data.equals("")) {
                                      Toast.makeText(Activity_Search.this, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        timer.cancel();
                                    }else {
                                      Toast.makeText(Activity_Search.this, "No results", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                  }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    },1,500);
                    Activity_Search.data = "";
                }
```

//Asynctask.java

```
    public class AsyncTaskSearch extends AsyncTask{
    public String link="";
    public String text="";


    public AsyncTaskSearch(String link,String text){

        this.link=link;
        this.text=text;

    }
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        try{
            String data= URLEncoder.encode("text","UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(text,"UTF8");

            URL url=new URL(link);
            URLConnection connection=url.openConnection();

            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter writer=new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            writer.write(data);
            writer.flush();
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();

            String line=null;

            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                builder.append(line);

            }

            Activity_Search.data=builder.toString();


        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: post the code of `AsyncTaskSearch` to get better feedback on how to organize the Toast, but my comment still stands - you wanna toast in the AsyncTask's onPostExecute.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are using your AysncTask. Try this code, it's working fine for me:

```
private class AsyncGetClass extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String TAG, url;
    AsyncHttpResponseHandler asyncHttpResponseHandler;
    Context context;

    public AsyncGetClass(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (!isProgressHiding)
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                progressDialog = createProgressDialog(context);
                progressDialog.show();
            } else {
                progressDialog.show();
            }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TAG = (String) params[0];
        url = (String) params[1];
        asyncHttpResponseHandler = (AsyncHttpResponseHandler) params[3];

        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";

        // HTTP post
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            Log.e(TAG, url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(Activity_Search.this, "No results", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            // Log.i(TAG + ".result", result);
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (!isProgressHiding)
            if (progressDialog != null)
                progressDialog.dismiss();
        if (result != null)
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, result);
                asyncHttpResponseHandler.onSuccess(result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Must implement the interface " + e.toString());
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are AysncTask is working fine and showing you the expected result then just override the method "OnPostExecute()" in your AysncTask class and remove your "Toast" Showing code and condition from "doInBackground()" method and put in the "onPostExecute()" method.

Comment: Put that toast code in "AysncTask" class and not in your main class.